# Why does my bar chart using scaleBand not line up with my tick marks?

Tags: d3.js

I'm plotting number of farmers by their race, with number of farmers on the y-axis and race on the x-axis. For the x-axis I'm using `d3.scaleBand()` which creates the x-axis perfectly, but when I add the bars, they don't line up with the tick marks unless I also call `.paddingInner(1).paddingOuter(1)` like so:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(races)
        .rangeRound([0, width])
    //why do I need these lines?
      .paddingInner(1).paddingOuter(1);
```

In other examples I've looked at they don't have to use those functions to get their charts to work:
https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4

Here's my code in a codepen
https://codepen.io/ericdjohnson/pen/6f7fda592032904943f0bdff0d9720a6/

Comment: It's actually not necessary.  You've set up the bar width and the x attribute on the bars in such a way that the padding is the only thing left to move the bars back to the line.

Comment: I'm setting the x attribute using `.attr('x', d=>xScale(d.race) - barWidth/2)` ... what should I use instead?

Comment: Change the `barwidth` to `xScale.bandwidth()` and delete from the x attribute `- barWidth/2` and you'll see the difference

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me fork a private Code Pen to illustrate.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll publish it... https://codepen.io/ericdjohnson/pen/zpJGzY/

Comment: It looks like `xScale.bandwith()` is outputting `0` currently.

Comment: Ok, updated here with a few comments in the code - though it looks like you were already there: https://codepen.io/mortonanalytics/pen/baxVNZ

Comment: You forgot the second d in `bandwidth()`

Comment: Oh `.paddingInner(1).paddingOuter(1)` were making `xScale.bandwidth()` zero. Sigh. Is there a way I can give you credit for an answer?

Comment: Sure. Posted an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not so much a requirement as a design choice when you made the `var barWidth = 20` and then translated the bar's `x` attribute by `- barWidth/2`. You could generate a similar graph by just manipulating the padding between 0 and 1 and letting the `xScale` do it's job: https://codepen.io/mortonanalytics/pen/baxVNZ